# Can't find any information about response error when do /act_{ad_account_ID}/users request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I do POST request:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/act_xxx/users?access_token=xxx
with uid and role params.

I've got a response like this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid parameter",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 1359066,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Invalid User",
        "error_user_msg": "To add someone to your ads account, please enter the e-mail address associated with a Facebook account.  Otherwise, you can enter the name of a friend.",
        "fbtrace_id": "ALvq6cchzWv"
    }
}
```

There is no information about this error in doc:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/aduser/v2.12

Previously, this request worked correctly.

Whats the reason of this error? Where should I enter e-mail address associated with a Facebook account or name of a friend?

Now I use ads_read, ads_management permissions, but I tried other and it was not successful too.

The same problem with v3 api.

Comment: Where did you get the user id from, and does it belong to your app?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, uid is the id of application admin